# Find "Active" items in a list not followed by "InActive" Items

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a list

```
 public class CarRent
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
  var mylist = new List<CarRent>() {
                new CarRent() { Brand = "Toyota",Date=DateTime.Parse( "1/10/14"),Status="Active" },//1
                new CarRent() { Brand = "Honda",Date=DateTime.Parse( "5/3/14"),Status="Active" },//2
                new CarRent() { Brand = "Toyota",Date=DateTime.Parse( "6/28/14"),Status="InActive" },//3
                new CarRent() { Brand = "Toyota",Date=DateTime.Parse( "12/12/14"),Status="Active" },//4
                new CarRent() { Brand = "Honda",Date=DateTime.Parse( "12/14/14"),Status="InActive" },//5
                new CarRent() { Brand = "Ford",Date=DateTime.Parse( "3/22/15"),Status="Active" },//6
                new CarRent() { Brand = "Ford",Date=DateTime.Parse( "12/12/15"),Status="InActive" },//7
                 new CarRent() { Brand = "Ford",Date=DateTime.Parse( "6/15/16"),Status="Active" },//8
            };
```

I need to find the item(s) in the list where the status is "Active" and not followed by "InActive" status.
For Example: Item 1 - Brand "Toyota" and status "Active" is followed by item 3 of same brand, later date and "Inactive", but Item 4 of same Brand with "Active" status and Date greater than item 1 and 3 and has no following "Inactive" status of same brand. So Item 4 qualifies.

From the Above list the expected result is Item 4 and Item 8.

How do I do this ?

Comment: Items of the same brand?

Comment: Then, would first item ("Toyota", Active) followed by ("Honda", Active) qualify too? I mean, do you compare only items of the same brand?

Comment: frst item ("Toyota", Active) followed by ("Honda", Active) will not qualify.. I need to compare items of same brand

Comment: Can you have two "Active" statuses of the same brand w/o "InActive" between? i.e. does "Active" and "Inactive" status toggle? In your example the above holds.

Comment: I can have two "Active" status of same brand w/o "InActive" in between

Comment: Then if you have "Active", "Active", "InActive", what is the expected output?

Comment: No output.. since an "Inactive" is followed by both "Active"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the items that are Active with no "InActive" after them can make lists in a dictionary, and clear when you get an "InActive" status, then select all the values that are in the cache when you are done iterating

```
var cache = new Dictionary<string,List<CarRent>>();

for(int i=0; i<myList.Count; i++)
{
    var curr = myList[i];

    if(!cache.ContainsKey(curr.Brand))
    {
        cache[curr.Brand]=new List<CarRent>();
    }

    if(curr.Status == "InActive")
        cache[curr.Brand].Clear();

    else if(curr.Status == "Active")
        cache[curr.Brand].Add(curr);

}

var results = cache.Values.SelectMany(a=>a);
```

Comment: This solution works for the list in the question and also if there is Two "Active" items of same Brand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filteredList = mylist
    .OrderBy(item => iten.Date)
    .GroupBy(item => item.Brand)
    .SelectMany(itemsGroup => itemsGroup.Where((item, index) => item.Status == "Active" &&
        mylist.ElementAtOrDefault(index + 1)?.Status != "InActive");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Error:operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool'

Comment: This returns item 2. expected is item 4 and 8

Comment: Remove the `ThenBy` and the Brand check inside the `Where`
Updated the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer to group the item by brand before searching for valid items.

Comment: Changed `== "InActive"` to `!= "InActive"`, that should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way possible:

```
var results = mylist.GroupBy(x => x.Brand)
                .Select(x => x.LastOrDefault())
                .Where(x => x.Status == "Active").ToList();
```

You need the last item of each brand only if it is "Active".

Comment: It doesn't handle the case where a valid item (or items) can appear inside a group of brands.
Such as: "Active" "InActive" "Active" "InActive" "Active".

Comment: @ItayPodhajcer that doesn't seem to be the requirement of the OP.

Comment: This solution works for the the list in the question and for scenario "the last item of each brand only if it is "Active" " . If there is Two "Active" items of same brand (add new item to list new CarRent() { Brand = "Toyota",Date=DateTime.Parse( "12/13/16"),Status="Active" },//9)  this returns the latest date of the two "Active" items

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
var result =
    (from rent in mylist
     group rent by rent.Brand into brandRents
     let lastInactive = brandRents
        .Where(r => r.Status == "InActive")
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .Aggregate((rent1, rent2) => rent2.Date > rent1.Date ? rent2 : rent1)
     from rent in brandRents
     where rent.Status == "Active" && 
        (lastInactive == null || rent.Date > lastInactive.Date)
     select rent).ToList();
```

You group the list by brand, then for each group find the latest inactive element (if any) and select all active elements after it.

It might seem complicated for what it does, but LINQ is not very well suited for processing sequence element relations.